# Finding all non-negative integer combinations of relatively prime integers

Tags: proof-explanation, integers

The problem, which I believe I solved (but don't fully understand), was to find all possible combinations $3a + 7b$ where $a,b \geq 0$ are integers. (Since the problem was about making paymens, I assume that the combination itself will not equal $0$.) This is a homework problem from an old course I'm following, so I was able to view and follow the professor's solution. It seemed, however, a little like pulling a rabbit out of a hat, so I am very curious of whether there is a more systematic approach.

Here is a quick sketch. of the argument, paraphrased:

- We can first construct, as combinations of $3$ and $7$, the elements: $3,6,7,9,10$. Any other element less than $12$ cannot work. Most of these I was able to show with a conceptual argument, but ruling out $11$ required a rather long proof by contradiction. I supposed $11$ could be written in the form $3a + 7b$, and then broke down $11$ into $21 - 3 - 7$.That allowed me to factor out $3$ on one side and $7$ on the other, and ultimately find a positive integer less than $21$ that divides $3$ and $7$, contradicting the fact that they are relatively prime. (This is another argument which was ultimately beautiful, but felt like a rabbit out of a hat!)

-The proof then asserts that any $n \geq 12$ can be accounted for. It gave three base cases, $n = 12$,$n=13$, and $n=14$.

- Then it assumed inductively that the conclusion held for all $12 \leq m < n - 15$. Then $n - 3$ has this form, so $n-3 = 3a + 7b$, so $n = 3(a+1) + 7b$.

---

The main things that I don't understand or for which I don't know where they came from are:

- The fact that $11$ cannot be written as an integer combination of $3$ and $7$. I tried to write out a general solution form, say, $a$ in terms of $b$, but didn't have a good way to rule out it could ever be a non-negative integer.
- Knowing why it is the case that any $n \geq 12$ can be accounted for. The proof of it is beautiful and I cannot follow each step of it, but how would I "guess" that this is the case in order to know to prove it? I tried to simulate this problem using R quite a few times, and it gave me such large numbers that it was difficult to discern any kind of reasonable pattern.

Comment: Did you mean “I supposed $11$ could be written in the form $3a+7b$”?

Comment: @Divide1918 Yes, thank you. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, there are in fact many ways to show $11$ cannot be written in the form $3a+7b$ with $a,b\gt 0$. The idea of the method seems to be that, if $11=3a+7b$, then $21=11+3+7=(3a+7b)+3+7=3(a+1)+7(b+1)$, whence examining the equation module $3$ and $7$ (and this is motivated by the fact that they are the only primes explicitly involved in the equation) gives the desired contradiction. Put another way, this motivates breaking up $11$ into $11=21-3-7$.

Notice that, however, if we lift the conditions on $a,b$, it is possible by Bézout’s identity, for instance $a=-1,b=2$ gives $3\cdot (-1)+7\cdot 2=11$. But as $3a+7b=11$ defines a linear relation, it should also be clear that if one were to alter the values of $a,b$ so as to obtain another solution, it must be the case that $3a$ decreases the same amount as $7b$ increases or vice versa. However, this is only possible if $a$ changes by some multiple of $7$ and $b$ by some multiple of $3$. If we decrease $a$, then $a$ would still be negative, but if we instead increase $a$, then we would have to decrease $b$ by at least $3$ and hence $b\le 2-3=-1\lt 0$. This produces another proof of the above fact.

As for the second part, where induction was used, this is motivated by noticing if the form works for $n$ then the same form works for $n+3$, which implies if we have $3$ consecutive integers which could all be written n the form $3a+7b$, then every integer which comes after can. So we try to find them.

Moreover,this in a way motivates the search in the beginning of the proof. We searched up to $11$, because from $12$ on everything could be written in the form $3a+7b$.